# In an msbuild reference element, what is advantage of specifying the processor architecture?

Tags: .net, msbuild

Or in other words, what is the differente between these two include values?

```
<Reference Include="Api.Core, Version=1.0.1.243, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b8761d376eb50bae">

<Reference Include="Api.Core, Version=1.0.1.243, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b8761d376eb50bae, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
```

I'm seeing both reference types in the same solution (different projects obviously) and I'm trying to undestand what the implication is. Both references were added through visual studio.

Comment: It is an optional part of the display name of an assembly.  A rough guess is that you saw it because Nuget added the reference.  Whether it is present or not just doesn't matter, .NET metadata is architecture independent.  It only starts to matter at runtime.  But "MSIL" is never a problem, the jitter takes care of generating the proper flavor of machine code.  You don't have a real problem.

Comment: Bottom line, it doesn't matter. You can compile even against assemblies of wrong architecture. You only need right assemblies at runtime. In fact, you will probably do as well using only `<Reference Include="Api.Core">`

Comment: Interesting... so if I understand completely it is not required at all, and it only matters that the correct assembly is present at run. And it sounds like you are saying this also applies to version, culture and maybe even public key token?

Comment: No, version works differently. Reverence's version is registered inside compiled assembly. Generally, you can use any version that is same or larger than `x.x.x.y` where "y" doesn't matter. You can set flag "specific version". And there is also version redirection that can be applied in `.config` file